# DroidGap: how get webpage?

Tags: android, cordova

My source:

```
    public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }


    @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
    // Now what page ??

            return true;
        }
```

How to get the current web page?

Comment: can you please elaborate your requirement

Comment: There is a web page, clicked on the screen I want to know what is now active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one external javascript file, write following code in it:

```
<script>
document.getElementByTagName("body").addEventListener('touchstart',touchPagePressed);// you can use 'onclick' also
function touchPagePressed()
{
   alert(touchPagePressed');
   var sPath=window.location.pathname; 
   var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
   alert(sPage); 
   MyAndroid.performClick(sPage);
}
</script>
```

include that external js file in every html page.

after this, write following code in your onCreate method:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
             {
                public void performClick(String currentPageName)
                {
                   // Deal with a click on the body tag
                   System.out.println("PageName- "+currentPageName);  
                }
             },"MyAndroid");
}
}
```

Comment: I do not R.id.webView ... =(

Comment: In view layout please check the WebView Name and modify accordingly

Comment: but the android market is not used, the code is not present setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html please have look at this blog in detail